# How do I securely reference ASP classic include files outside of web root?

Tags: security, asp-classic

I'd like to be able to place all my ASP Classic include files outside of the web root. This assures no include files can be called directly via the URL.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I know I can use a [virtual directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx) to reference an includes folder outside of web root, but doesn't that still allow direct access to that directory via the URL? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the nature of virtual directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not recommended, you could also enable the 'Enable parent paths' option in IIS, which will allow you to reference files outside the webroot via the include directive, as well as allow access via the filesystemobject.  This is generally not recommended though, as it does pose a security risk.

For directions on how to do this, check out the [Enabling Parent Paths article on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/40993ff2-22c3-48a9-ba01-1056a9425a1e.mspx?mfr=true).

It's been a while since I used Classic ASP, but generally, I'd only declare subroutines and functions in include files, and then call those from the main application code.  This has the unintended side effect where if someone does guess the path to an include and accesses the file directly via their browser, it wouldn't actually do anything as no code is executed.

Answer (score 2):

From [this article](http://forums.iis.net/t/1148178.aspx):

(I've never need to do this myself)

> Understood.  Make a virtual directory
>   'inside' your Default Web Site that
>   points to the files 'outside' your
>   working folder.  In your code
>   reference the virtual directory that
>   points to the folder / files outside
>   your normal structure.  For example
>
> Your default website is a local folder
>   called c:\websites\example.com.  Under
>   example.com, all your folders and
>   files.  However, the files you want on
>   a file server called FileServerA in a
>   folder called D:\MyWebsiteIncludes. 
>   The UNC path is
>   \FileServerA\D$\MyWebSiteIncludes or
>   if you create a share on the folder,
>   \FileServerA\MyWebsiteIncludes  On
>   the web server, create a virtual
>   directory that maps to either share
>   path.  You'll need to make sure the
>   proper credentials are configured to
>   access the files on the remote server.

Comment: great.. this is much better than the accepted answer. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check the procedure mentioned in [Diodeus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272696/87015) and it actually worked.

#### Example Files/Folders Setup:

```
E:\includes\
           \include.asp
           \another.asp
E:\websites\
           \business-website.com\
                                \config.asp
                                \default.asp
           \personal-website.com\
                                \config.asp
                                \default.asp
           \whatever-website.com\
                                \config.asp
                                \default.asp
```

#### IIS Website Setup

```
business-website.com -> E:\websites\business-website.com\
     v. dir /include -> E:\includes\
personal-website.com -> E:\websites\personal-website.com\
     v. dir /include -> E:\includes\
whatever-website.com -> E:\websites\whatever-website.com\
     v. dir /include -> E:\includes\
```

Note: virtual directories were not converted to applications.

#### What works in the `default.asp`

```
Files in current directory:
<!-- #include file="config.asp" -->

Files in current directory (using virtual path):
<!-- #include virtual="/config.asp" -->

Files in include directory:
<!-- #include virtual="/include/include.asp" -->
```

#### What works in the virtually included `include.asp`

```
Files in current directory:
<!-- #include file="another.asp" -->

Files in current directory (using virtual path):
<!-- #include virtual="/include/another.asp" -->

Files in root application:
<!-- #include virtual="/config.asp" -->
```

This makes it much easier to consolidate all include files into one place.